# Suppose that $ T\in \mathcal L (V) $ is normal. Prove that $T^{*} = -T $ iff every eigenvalue of T is purely imaginary.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $ T\in \mathcal L (V) $ is normal. Prove that $T^{*} = -T $ iff every eigenvalue of T is purely imaginary.

$(\Rightarrow)$ assume $T^{*} = -T $ Suppose $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue with an eigenvector $v\neq 0 $

$$\lambda \| v\|^2 = \lambda \langle v,v \rangle $$
$$ =  \langle \lambda v,v \rangle  $$
$$ =  \langle T v,v \rangle  $$
$$ =  \langle  v,T^{*} v \rangle  $$
$$ =  \langle  v,-T v \rangle  $$
$$ =  \langle  v,-\lambda v \rangle  $$
$$ = -\bar{\lambda} \langle  v, v \rangle  $$
$$ = -\bar{\lambda} \| v\|^2 $$
this shows us for any $ \lambda = - \bar \lambda $ so all eigenvalues are imaginary.

$(\Leftarrow ) $ Assume all the eigenvalues are imaginary WTS $T^*= -T$ can someone help me with this direction?

Comment: I imagine you need to use that $T$ is normal to reduce to an eigenbasis. At that point it should follow from the definition of $T^\ast$.

Comment: If you can use the spectral theorem, then the proof is pretty quick.  Have you covered the spectral theorem yet?

Comment: I have how do i apply it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Longleftarrow$: Assume that $T$ is normal with imaginary eigenvalues.  By the spectral theorem, there exists a unitary $U$ such that
$$
T = U\pmatrix{\lambda_1\\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n}U^*
$$
Since the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are imaginary, we compute
$$
T^* = \left[U\pmatrix{\lambda_1\\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n}U^*\right]^* = U \pmatrix{\bar \lambda_1\\ & \ddots \\ && \bar \lambda_n} U^* = 
- U \pmatrix{\lambda_1\\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n} U^* = -T
$$
as desired.

Comment: Alternatively, you might already have a result which says that a normal matrix is Hermitian iff its eigenvalues are real.  If you have this result, it suffices to make the observation that
$$
T^* = -T \iff (iT)^* = iT
$$

Comment: In that second $=$, by the way, we note that $(ABC)^* = C^*B^*A^*$.

Comment: we haven't covered unitary matrices at this point in the book so i doubt this was the intended method but thank you

Comment: @Faust whichever version of the spectral theorem you're used to leads to a similar proof.  If you have an orthonormal eigenbasis, then it suffices to note that you can write the transformation as 
$$
T = \sum_i \lambda_i v_iv_i^*
$$

Comment: Yeah i figured it out thanks. ^^